# Groovy+ XML: handle Attributes with Namespace-Prefix

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I'm working on a XML-document with Groovy and test a node for a certain attribute, which has a  namespace prefix. How could it work:

in groovy-script:

```
...
Element.Subelement.each {
  if (it.'@type'=='ns2:xyType')
    ...do what ever...
}
```

in XML document:

```
<Element>
   <Subelement xsi:type="ns2:xyType"> 
      <!-- or another type, want to do something with      
           subelement only if type is "ns2:xyType" -->
   </Subelement>
</Element>
```

Looking for something like:

```
if (it.'@xsi:type'=='ns2:xyType')
```

THX
Seldon

Answer (score 2):

Well, your document is a little confusing, since it seems that neither xsi nor ns2 namespaces were ever declared, but I'm going to assume they were declared somewhere in the complete doc.

From [The Groovy Docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)

```
def wsdl = '''
<definitions name="AgencyManagementService"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/NS1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/NS2">
    <ns1:message name="SomeRequest">
        <ns1:part name="parameters" element="SomeReq" />
    </ns1:message>
    <ns2:message name="SomeRequest">
        <ns2:part name="parameters" element="SomeReq" />
    </ns2:message>
</definitions>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(wsdl).declareNamespace(ns1: 'http://www.example.org/NS1', ns2: 'http://www.example.org/NS2')
println xml.'ns1:message'.'ns1:part'.size()
println xml.'ns2:message'.'ns2:part'.size()
```

For your example (note, you'll have to fill in the URLs for the namespaces):

```
def ggg = '''
<Element xmlns:xsi="http://www.example.org/xsi"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/NS2">
   <Subelement xsi:type="ns2:xyType"> 
      <SubSub name="bob" />
   </Subelement>
</Element>
'''
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(ggg).declareNamespace(xsi: 'http://www.example.org/xsi', ns2: 'http://www.example.org/NS2')
def elem = xml.'Subelement'
if ( elem.'@xsi:type'.text() == 'ns2:xyType' ){
   // do it  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ridiculous how there is no mention of how to do this in the official documentation.

Here's what I've found works (Groovy 2.4)

```
def element = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
assert element.Subelement.'@xsi:type' == 'ns2:xyType'
```

Where you pass in false for namespaceAware when you create the the XmlSlurper or Parser.

Answer (score 1):

```
def xsi = new groovy.xml.Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")  
node.attributes()[xsi.type] == 'my_type'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (groovy 1.8.4). Given an XML doc of:

```
<container>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="woo:FAMILY">
      <id>111</id>
      <name>Family 1</name>
   </item>
</container>
```

This assert passes:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlDocStr)
assert "woo:FAMILY" == xml.item.'@xsi:type'.text()
```

Note you do have to have the .text() though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also re-create the full attribute identifier (it's a `QName`) in the code and use that to look up the attribute value:

```
final QName classAttributeKey = new QName("http://example.org/", "attributeKeyAKALocalPart", "prefix")
String attributeValue = yourNode.attribute(classAttributeKey)
```